# How to detect changes in the value of an input text on key press Angular 6

Tags: angular6

I need to handle something on html input text, `distinctUntilChanged` not working properly, text cycle by each character in Angular 6. 
How do I solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working correctly"?  Do you have an error message?  Is there any example code you can share?  As is, you do not provide nearly enough information for us to reasonably solve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, ViewChild, OnInit } 
from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, map, distinctUntilChanged, filter } from 
rxjs/operators'


@Component({
 selector: 'app-child',
 template: `
 <input #inputSearch placeholder="Write something"/>`
})
export class HijoComponent implements OnInit {

@Output() inputText: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

@ViewChild('inputSearch') inputSearch: ElementRef

constructor(){  

}

ngOnInit(){
  fromEvent(this.inputSearch.nativeElement, 'keyup').
    pipe(
        map((evt: any) => evt.target.value),
        filter(res => res.length > 2),  
        debounceTime(1000),
        distinctUntilChanged()  

      ).subscribe((c : string)=> {      
        this.inputText.emit(c)
        }); 
} 

}
```